# how to write linq "group by" and get count based on row in asp.net mvc

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, group-by

I have two tables  timesheet and timesheet_log

In timesheet i have three columns id,comp_id,emp_id and in timesheet_log table,
i have three columns id, timesheet_id, stat.

Now I want to group all the "STAT" column by "COMP_ID", for that i wrote query in sql

```
select tlog.stat,count(*) as count  from  timesheet ts
join
timesheet_log  tlog on ts.id = tlog.timesheet_id
where comp_id=10//For ex.
group by tlog.stat
```

In stat column contains each rows like "Not_Entered","Not_submitted" etc..,
when i executing above query in sql server,i getting result like

result:
**Stat**                 **Count**
Not_entered            10 
Not_Submitted       8...
..................
-------------------

Now, I want to write the query in linq and assign variable count of each row to a varaible like:

if Not_entered count in 10 then
int emp_not_entered= //Count of Not entered.

I have tried in linq like

```
        var result= (from timesheet in reslandentity.TIMESHEET
                                join tlog in reslandentity.TIMESHEET_LOG on timesheet.ID equals tlog.TIMESHEET_ID
                                group tlog by tlog.STAT into g

                                select   g).ToString();
```

But not getting what i expected, Help me anyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access grouping key (value of STAT in your case) via `Key` property of grouping. To get count of items in each group just call `Count()` on group:

```
var result = from timesheet in reslandentity.TIMESHEET
             join tlog in reslandentity.TIMESHEET_LOG 
                  on timesheet.ID equals tlog.TIMESHEET_ID
             group tlog by tlog.STAT into g
             select new { Stat = g.Key, Count = g.Count() };
```

Keep in mind - this query will return `IQueryable` of some anonymous type with two properties - Stat and Count. Calling `ToString()` makes no sense here, because you will just get type name.

Comment: can you show me as example to get the value based on key?

Comment: @sanjay simplest `var count = result.First(x => x.Stat == "Not_entered").Count` (it does not check if key exist). Also you can put all values into dictionary: `var stats = result.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count)` and use it as any other dictionary

Comment: i got it like  int EMPLOYEES_NOT_SUBMITTED = dashboardDetails.Where(m => m.STAT == "NOT_SUBMITTED").Select(m => m.COUNT).FirstOrDefault();